# returning shared_ptr member of an rvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, rvalue

In C++ Concurrency In Action - Practical MultiThreading page 167, there's the code snipet

```
 std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
 {
     std::unique_ptr<node> const old_head=wait_pop_head();
     return old_head->data;
 }
```

Why do we have to move assign rvalue `wait_pop_head()` to a const variable first? Is there a reason why we can't shorthand the code to following?

```
std::shared_ptr<T> wait_and_pop()
{
    return wait_pop_head()->data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no reason that your alternative could not be used.

The temporary will live long enough.

But some people just prefer to write it out.

Comment: is it because with`wait_pop_head()->data` `wait_pop_head()` is a temp variable and wont exist unless it is assigned to a const reference?

Comment: @GradyPlayer: No. It lives long enough in either case.

Comment: @GradyPlayer: The temporary will live until the end of the statement in which it appears. In this case, that (basically) means it'll live until the `return` is done, which was true of the first code too.

Comment: Arguably the fact that now two people on this page are questioning the second code's correctness is reason enough not to use it, its _actual_ correctness notwithstanding...

Comment: @GradyPlayer: Why not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167901/discussion-between-grady-player-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).